# Kак сконвертировать все файлы в папке в кодировку utf-8

Tags: linux, файлы, кодировка, iconv

Есть папка с большим количеством вложенных папок и файлов с кодировкой windows-1251(более 500). Нужно конвертировать все файлы в этой папке и ее вложенных папках в utf-8.
Для каждого файла выполнять

```
iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8 file > file.utf8
```

будет долго.
Как сделать это быстрее?

Comment: Наваять скрипт на баше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find -type f -exec iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8 '{}' -o '{}.utf8' \;
```

Comment: Наверное, всё же *{}.utf8*.